# Why is every Gaussian process a linear process?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, time-series

In Section 4.2.4 of [1], the authors write

> In this section we consider a causal linear process
> $$
> X_t = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j \varepsilon_{t - j}, \quad t \in \mathbb{N},
> $$
> where, without loss of generality, $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j^2 = 1$ and $\varepsilon_t$ $(t \in \mathbb{Z})$ are i.i.d. zero mean random variables with Var$(\varepsilon_1) = \sigma^2_\varepsilon < \infty$. Thus, Var$(X_1) = \sigma^2_X = \sigma^2_\varepsilon$. Note that
> Gaussian processes are included in this definition, but the class is much more general.

I read the last sentence as "all Gaussian processes are causal linear processes". And [2] seems to support that. It argues that *"...the Mallows MA closure is exhausted by three types of processes. The first type is the set of stationary Gaussian processes with mean zero..."*.

However, a counter-example can be constructed by a Gaussian process which is defined as $X(t) = Y$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$ where $Y$ is a zero-mean Gaussian random variable. This is an (admittedly degenerate) Gaussian process and I fail to see how it can be expressed as a linear process.

So, is my counter-example wrong? Or do we need additional assumptions for a Gaussian process to be a (causal) linear process? [1] often works with regularly varying auto-covariance functions resp. spectral densities. Has this maybe been assumed implicitly? If so, how do these assumptions help to prove the claim?

## References

[1] J. Beran, Y. Feng, S. Ghosh, and R. Kulik. Long-memory processes. Springer, 2016.

[2] https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.93.22.12128

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee : Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\N{\mathbb N}$Your counterexample is correct. Indeed, if
$$X_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j \ep_{t-j} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for $t\in\N$, $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j^2=1$, and the $\ep_t$'s are iid zero-mean random variables with variance  $\si^2\in(0,\infty)$, then for $u\in\N$
$$EX_tX_{t+u}=\si^2\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_ja_{j+u}\to0$$
as $u\to\infty$, by the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality.

This contradicts the condition that $X_t=Y$ for all $t$, because then we would have $EX_tX_{t+u}=EX_1^2=\si^2>0$ for all $u\in\N$.

---

Generally (see e.g. [Theorem 2, p. 263](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-3-642-61943-4%2F1.pdf)), a  Gaussian process $(X_t)$ is of the form \eqref{1} if and only if $(X_t)$ is a zero-mean stationary process with $EX_t^2<\infty$ which has an absolutely continuous spectral measure and its spectral
density $f$ satisfies the condition
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\ln f(t)\,dt>-\infty$$
(so that $f$ does not get too close to $0$ on any set of significant enough Lebesgue measure).

(In your counterexample, the spectral measure is degenerate, a multiple of the Dirac measure supported on the singleton set $\{0\}$, and hence not all absolutely continuous.)

Comment: Thanks. That's reassuring to hear. Do you have a guess what the authors of [1] and [2] mean instead?

Comment: @AlbertRapp : My best guess about what the authors meant to say here is that they simply wanted to say that the $\varepsilon_t$'s may (but do not have to) be Gaussian. Anyhow , I have now provided an if-and-only-if condition.

Comment: Nice! Your additional theorem is exactly what I have been looking for. The condition is the iff-condition for a time-series to be non-deterministic. I've suspected that this is related. But Brockwell & Davis did not specify this as an iff-condition w.r.t. to the Wold decomposition.